# arm rig does not follow rotation

Tags: rigging

I followed Polyfjord latest tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtlLUdUvw-g&t=907s), unfortunately i made some beginner mistake.

I copied just the arm rig here so you can reproduce it:

As you can see here, i have massive problems with rotations (or objects to follow the bone correctly):

[image]

i have no idea what i made wrong.

Blend file:[image]

rig:

[image]

in the rest pose, the rotations are correct:

[image]

on frame 212 it's looking fine:

[image]

on 223 it's already messed up:

[image]

update: i could solve now this connection here by deconnecting the bones and moving the bone end points to the center of the holes:

[image]

But i still got problems at the end parts.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're trying to use mocap to animate a mesh that implies certain limited range of motion-- limits that don't necessarily exist on the original mocap data.  Yet you have no constraints on your bones or objects to enforce these limits; if you did enforce them, there is no guarantee that the constrained animation would look much at all like the original.  Is the question, how to retarget animation from a human to a robot?  I haven't watched the video; it's long, and it looks like they're doing quite a bit more than you have so far.

Comment: Yes, the animation is downloaded from mocap - if you mean that. And Polyfjord didn't use any constraints too. But unfortunately his tutorial isn't that detailed like others of his tutorials. So i might have missed some steps. And for sure i am not a pro rigger - i still have to learn a lot about rigging. And i am also not sure whether his way really works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lack of joints.

[image]

Note: I haven't watched the tutorial.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood you, but if i just add a bone there, the animation is still not working. Can u maybe provide your corrected blend file or do i have to do something else but just adding a bone? Sorry, i am not a rigging-pro....but did you copy a bone or how did you add that bone? I tried with subdivide....and if i understand your picture right, you now propose a solution for the middle part, which i solved already, is that right? i am searching a solution for the shoulder part. (the U - end)

Comment: and limit rotation won't work if the bones have already a keyframed animation...so your solution doesn't work